# Difficulty in setting permanent iptables on Debian

Tags: debian, iptables, debian-squeeze

I have problem setting permanent iptables on Debian 6 Squeeze.

I am working on a brand new instance of a server, freshly created, updated and upgraded to latest version.

Here is the tutorial I followed multiple times:

http://wiki.debian.org/iptables

I am doing all operations as root user.

After completing all the steps in the tutorial and rebooting server, the iptables are reset to default state ie. allow everything in and out.

My aim is to set them "for good", so they won't reset every time the system reboots.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using iptables-persistent or the scripts described in the wiki? What happens when you run your scripts?

Comment: I ran `apt-get install iptables-persistent` and followed the steps in the wiki (no, I did not use any scripts). Is there any additional configuration involved in iptables-persistent?

Comment: For the record, I suggest you look at something like firehol, ufw, shorewall, or some other iptables front end.  Creating a really strong set of rules by hand can get pretty difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first a clarification, did you use the instructions from the Debian Wiki, or did you use the `iptables-persistent` package?  They operate via different mechanisms.  The Wiki page is basically describing a manually way of accomplishing what `iptables-peristent` does.

If you installed `iptables-persistent`, did you put your iptables rules in the file `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` (as described in the `iptables-persistent` documentation)?  If not, that's probably your issue.  Try configuring your iptables rules the way you want them, and then run either:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
```

If you didn't use `iptables-persistent`, but copied the changes required by the Debian Wiki page, you'll need to show us the modifications you made to the files, the if-pre-up script you added, etc.

**UPDATE:** The `iptables-persistent` information above is for the package in wheezy (testing) and sid (unstable).  For squeeze (stable), the file should be `/etc/iptables/rules`.  Unfortunately, I don't have an easily accessible squeeze/stable based box, so I can't look closer at `iptables-persistent` on it right now.

Comment: Let's go with the iptables-persistent method. I pasted my rules into `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and ran `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`. The iptables did not update. I tried to restart iptables-persistent and also do a reboot, but the `iptables -L` stays empty.

Comment: The command `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` would over-write anything you pasted into `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.  Are you sure you didn't mean to do a restore?

Comment: @Christopher, BTW are you sure the file isn't `/etc/iptables/rules` instead of `rules.v4`?  Is the v4 a wheeze thing perhaps, the `iptables-persistent` on squeeze seems to use a file named `rules`.

Comment: @Zoredache - Good point.  `rules.v4 `is what the wheezy (testing) and sid (unstable) packages are using.  `/etc/iptables/rules` is what the squeeze (stable) package looks to be using.  I'll update the answer info to note the differences.

Comment: I have done the same for `rules` (pasted my rules in there and saved using `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules`). Now I rebooted my machine and the changes did not save. Any more ideas? :)